# Build String Based on Data Stored in SQL Server XML Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've been attempting to write this query but, so far, to no avail.

The following is some partial data from an XML column in SQL Server:

```
<DashboardWidgets>
    <DashboardWidget id="14">
        <EnumName>PersonalProgressIndividual</EnumName>
        <OnOff>1</OnOff>
        <Movable>0</Movable>
        <Removable>0</Removable>
        <SubItemData>
            <SubItem id="1">
                <OnOff>1</OnOff>
                <Movable>1</Movable>
                <Removable>1</Removable>
            </SubItem>
            <SubItem id="2">
                <OnOff>1</OnOff>
                <Movable>1</Movable>
                <Removable>1</Removable>
            </SubItem>
            <SubItem id="3">
                <OnOff>1</OnOff>
                <Movable>1</Movable>
                <Removable>1</Removable>
            </SubItem>
            <SubItem id="4">
                <OnOff>0</OnOff>
                <Movable>0</Movable>
                <Removable>0</Removable>
            </SubItem>
            <SubItem id="6">
                <OnOff>0</OnOff>
                <Movable>0</Movable>
                <Removable>0</Removable>
            </SubItem>
        </SubItemData>
    </DashboardWidget>
</DashboardWidgets>
```

My goal is to query the table and retrieve a formatted string of IDs and values.

For an example, I would need to query the DashboardWidget node with the ID of 14 and build the string from the SubItemData child nodes contained within.

The string result required for a query of the dashboard widget with the ID of 14 would be:

```
"1,1,1,1|2,1,1,1|3,1,1,1|4,0,0,0|6,0,0,0"
```

I've been able to come close by extracting all the values but without any delimiters at all.

```
DECLARE
    @companyID  INT = 23
    ,@dwID      INT = 14
;

DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT @xml = c.DashboardWidgetSettings FROM dbo.Company c WHERE c.CompanyID = @companyID;

SELECT
    x.Rec.query('./SubItem').value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS 'SubItemData'
FROM @xml.nodes('/DashboardWidgets/DashboardWidget[@id=sql:variable("@dwID")]/SubItemData') as x(Rec)
;
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @XML xml = '<DashboardWidgets><DashboardWidget id="14"><EnumName>PersonalProgressIndividual</EnumName><OnOff>1</OnOff><Movable>0</Movable><Removable>0</Removable><SubItemData><SubItem id="1"><OnOff>1</OnOff><Movable>1</Movable><Removable>1</Removable></SubItem><SubItem id="2"><OnOff>1</OnOff><Movable>1</Movable><Removable>1</Removable></SubItem><SubItem id="3"><OnOff>1</OnOff><Movable>1</Movable><Removable>1</Removable></SubItem><SubItem id="4"><OnOff>0</OnOff><Movable>0</Movable><Removable>0</Removable></SubItem><SubItem id="6"><OnOff>0</OnOff><Movable>0</Movable><Removable>0</Removable></SubItem></SubItemData></DashboardWidget></DashboardWidgets>'

Select Stuff((Select Distinct '|' +String 
              From (
                    Select String = f.n.value('@id','varchar(50)') 
                                   +','
                                   +f.n.value('(OnOff)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                                   +','
                                   +f.n.value('(Movable)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                                   +','
                                   +f.n.value('(Removable)[1]','varchar(50)') 
                     From  @XML.nodes('DashboardWidgets/DashboardWidget/SubItemData') t(n)
                     Cross Apply t.n.nodes('SubItem ') f(n)
                   ) X
              For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
1,1,1,1|2,1,1,1|3,1,1,1|4,0,0,0|6,0,0,0
```

Comment: Wow! I can't thank you enough, John.  That's exactly what I needed and works perfectly! Cheers!

Comment: @webface Happy to help  :)